# custom form control adapter not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, control-adapter

I have a web site that has a custom control adapter built to rewrite the action on forms. (This is a site we inherited from another agency) When running on localhost in debug mode everything works great. But as soon as I publish the site to the server in our QA environment the custom adapter stops firing.

I've published with debug symbols and attached to the w3wp process. stepping through the page load process and the breakpoints set in the custom control adapter never get hit. When you run in debug on localhost they fire on every page load. The production code runs on the same server and the custom control adapter in production is working. But, we need to make an update to production and we're afraid we'll break the production site.

Does anyone have any idea why the custom control adapter would not fire on the server? I've never used custom adapters before, is there anything that needs to be done other than putting the adapter in the App_Code folder and the entry in the .browser file in the App_Browser folder?

**Adapter Code in the App_Code folder:**

```
public class FormRewriterControlAdapter : System.Web.UI.Adapters.ControlAdapter {

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        base.Render(new RewriteFormHtmlTextWriter(writer));
    }

}

public class RewriteFormHtmlTextWriter : HtmlTextWriter {
    public RewriteFormHtmlTextWriter(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        : base(writer) {
        InnerWriter = writer.InnerWriter;
    }
    public RewriteFormHtmlTextWriter(TextWriter writer)
        : base(writer) {
        InnerWriter = writer;
    }

    public override void WriteAttribute(string name, string value, bool fEncode) {
        // if the attribute we are writing is the "action" attribute, and we are not on a sub-control, 
        // then replace the value to write with the raw URL of the request - which ensures that we//ll
        // preserve the PathInfo value on postback scenarios

        if (name == "action") {
            HttpContext Context = HttpContext.Current;

            if (Context.Items["ActionAlreadyWritten"] == null) {
                // Because we are using the UrlRewriting.net HttpModule, we will use the 
                // Request.RawUrl property within ASP.NET to retrieve the origional URL
                // before it was re-written.  You//ll want to change the line of code below
                // if you use a different URL rewriting implementation.

                value = Context.Request.RawUrl;

                // Indicate that we//ve already rewritten the <form>//s action attribute to prevent
                // us from rewriting a sub-control under the <form> control

                Context.Items["ActionAlreadyWritten"] = true;
            }
        }

        base.WriteAttribute(name, value, fEncode);
    }
}
```

**And my .browser file in the App_Browser folder:**

```
<browsers>

  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm" adapterType="FormRewriterControlAdapter" />
      <!--<adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink" adapterType="LinkRewriterControlAdapter" />-->
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>

</browsers>
```